# Zend Framework Hostname Routes: Routing while ignoring subdomains

Tags: zend-framework

So I want to create a `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname` that matches the following:

- example.com
- www.example.com
- stage.example.com
- dev.example.com
- andrew.dev.example.com
- joe.dev.example.com

I can't seem to figure out how to create a route that can match all these things. There can be multiple subdomains before "example.com", so everything before it doesn't really matter. Here's what I have so far:

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(':sandbox.:environment.example.com', array('controller' => 'events', 'event-id' => $eventId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have multiple subomains match in a single hostname route. So here's what you have to do:

```
$hostnameRoutes = array(
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('example.com', array('controller' => 'events', 'event-id' => $eventId)),
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(':subdomain.example.com', array('controller' => 'events', 'event-id' => $eventId)),
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(':sandbox.dev.example.com', array('controller' => 'events', 'event-id' => $eventId))
);

$homepageRoute =         new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('',       array('action' => 'overview'));
$eventPagesRoute =       new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':action/*',     array('action' => 'overview'));
$staticEventPagesRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('page/:page-id', array('action' => 'static-page'));

foreach ($hostnameRoutes as $i => $hostnameRoute) {
    $router->addRoute('sports_homepage' . $i,          $hostnameRoute->chain($homepageRoute));
    $router->addRoute('sports_event_pages' . $i,       $hostnameRoute->chain($eventPagesRoute));
    $router->addRoute('sports_static_event_Page' . $i, $hostnameRoute->chain($staticEventPagesRoute));
}
```

Note: make sure the names of your routes are unique (note the `$i` being concatenated to make them unique). I forgot about that first time through and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't one route for non-linear mapping with more then two choices, so you'll have to use more then one ;) Without knowing the targets of each domain it's hard to give any examples. 
Assuming `example.com` and `www.example.com` are eaqual and are both the default route and `stage` and `dev` are both mapped to their respecitve module (and `andreaw` and `joe` as parameters) (and added to the router of course):

```
$stageRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('stage.example.com', array('module' => 'stage');
$devRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(':user.dev.example.com', array('module' => 'dev');
```

This will map the following (`:module/:controller/:action`):

- `stage.example.com` to `stage/index/index`
- `dev.example.com` to `dev/index/index`
- `joe.example.com` to `dev/index/index/user/joe`
- `www.example.com` to `default/index/index`

In words: if the sudomain is `stage` and nothing else, go to the `stage` module with default parameters. If the `subdomain` is `dev` go to the `dev` module with parameter `user`. Else use the default zend route.
Be careful that hostname routers do match any path. So you probably should match the path behind it with another route and using the [chain router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.chain).

For the stage route this could look like this:

```
$stageRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('stage.example.com', array('module' => 'stage');
$pathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':revision', array('controller' => 'browse'));
$stageRoute->chain($pathRoute);
```

That'd map `stage.example.com/5434` to `stage/browse/index/revision/5434`.