# How configure .htaccess, vhost, hosts to use Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname?

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, apache2, router

I read about Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname, but i havent idea how.
i try to use [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739478/zend-framework-hostname-routes-routing-while-ignoring-subdomains), [zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname). But when i try to open [someoneusername.localhost/](http://someoneusername.localhost/) my browser dont found nothing.( Oops! Google Chrome could not find ... ).

i verified my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     ServerName localhost   
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/zendtest/public"
     <Directory "/var/www/zendtest/public">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>   
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-localhost.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-localhost.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

please someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming everything else has been configured correctly, you'll want to change your VirtualHost Directive:

```
ServerName localhost
```

to

```
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias *.localhost
```

and then restart apache.
I'm afraid you're out of luck with the hosts file ([wildcards unsupported](https://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain))
See the link for alternatives.

Comment: someoneusername.localhost want to dynamic, johan.localhost, shad.localhost.

Comment: I installed dnsmasq and workS! wonderfull. i used the configuration proposed by Jeremy Kendall in [DNS WILDCARD](http://daniel.hahler.de/easy-dns-wildcard-setup-for-local-domains-using-dnsmasq/)